# Is display MacBook Pro fuse or software protected against overpowered/ short circuit?

Tags: macos, display, usb, backlight

I did accidentally overpowered (12v) the USB Port of My MacBook Pro 2015 by putting a powered male usb. (I know that is stupid of me).
Immediately the display and the light of my keyboard went off.
I hear on the sound of the MacBook that the Mac is still alive.

Now I am questioning myself.
-are the display and keyboard light dead and have to be replaced?
-is there any protection mode designed by smart apple engineers to protect such a rare situation. By for example a fuse (for backlight/display, I found on YouTube the replacement instructions already. For keyboard I didn’t yet found any) or a software mode?

I’m not able to search for any resource to help me solve this. What guides or steps are people using for this situation?

Comment: What precisely is a "powered male usb"?

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. With a powered male usb, I mean a usb which is supplying 12v power (this is used to charge my son’s AliExpress purchased drone). I Accidentally putted this in de USB port instead another usb which was laying next to each other.

Comment: Take is to an **Apple** store, or an **Apple** authorized service center and have it checked out.

Comment: @user3439894 that isn't nessecarily the right answer all the time. Assuming Barham had a TM backup, it wouldn't be a bad idea of replacing the display fuse, and if Barham really needs the keyboard backlight, to buy a top case and change it himself (assuming Barham feels comfortable working on electronics). Ive fixed a few Macs before, and its not that hard if your careful.

Comment: @anonymous, What I posted was a comment **not** an answer.

Comment: @anonymous; we are on the same page. I am on holiday currently. No access to the laptop right now. In the meantime I have studied many YouTube instructions. After my holiday I will perform a hard rest, then replace the fuse etc. Will update you all. Thanks!

Comment: @Bahram do you need a backlit keyboard? Top cases are quite expensive, so it would save you a lot of money if you were ok without keyboard backlighting.

Comment: I am not sure. It is handy to have one. I hope it is a matter of a defective fuse. Otherwise I will buy a secondhand laptop en put it over. I see also some offers on AliExpress:-)))

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I discovered that my U7700 is burned out and not the backlight fuse which should have protect the chip.
I have ordered a new chip and hotair gun at AliExpress. Replacement should be quite doable for a handy person.

Next to this:
I found out that a Complete new mother board Can be purchased at AliExpress for quite a fair price of €100. Which I did as well.

Keep you posted